# Знаки препинания в предложении: "Чисто ручная работа"

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Как пишется и где знак препинания, если он нужен в предложении: "Чисто ручная работа"?

Answer (score 3):

> ...и где знак препинания, **если он нужен** в предложении. "Чисто ручная
>   работа"

Нужна **точка** в конце предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Чисто ручная работа - это словосочетание, где "чисто - наречие с раздельным написанием.

Пояснение

Наречие "чисто" часто употребляется с переносным значением "исключительно, только; совсем, совершенно".

Примеры

Обыкновенное учреждение, выполняющее чисто технические функции. Существует ещё ряд проблем чисто эстетического характера. Комплекс берестяных грамот изучался сначала чисто исторически.

Answer (score 1):

Вы написали верно, знаки препинания не нужны.